# ElasticSearch with python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

How to use elasticsearch with python and which framework/software/text-editor to use to write python code for elasticsearch. I am a beginner so a bit confused.
thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is way too broad. What have you tried codewise, where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have python already running in your system,

You can install elastic search in python using-

> pip install elasticsearch

Regarding software or framework you can use any IDE that supports and runs python such as jetbrains PyCharm or an IPython notebook

Ps: If you're new I'd suggest you go through the documents here extensively-

> https://www.elastic.co/learn